# Create tree structure from csv data for collapse menu

Tags: python, json, pandas, tree

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))))

    for row in df.itertuples():
        d[row[1]][row[2]][row[3]][row[4]].append(row[5])
    d = json.dumps(d)
    d = json.loads(d)
```

I have this code that reads some csv data as a dataframe. I found a way to create a tree-like structure using defaultdict, and then looping through the df and populating it. *The data will always have the same depth*
Analyzer: Mode: SubMode: Filename: Signal

The result looks like this:

```
{
  "Analyzer1": {
    "Mode1": { "SubMode1": { "filename2": ["Signal1"] } },
    "Mode2": {
      "SubMode2": {
        "filename1": [
          "Signal2",
          "Signal3"
        ]
      }
    },
    "Mode3": {
      "SubMode1": {
        "filename1": ["Signal2"]
      },
      "SubMode3": {
        "filename1": ["Signal3"]
      }
    }
  },
  "Analyzer2": {
    "Mode1": {
      "SubMode4": {
        "filename1": ["Signal2"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is great, but I'm obligated to do some changes to the final result, as this tree will be used with a react package for displaying collapsible menus (react-checkbox-tree: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-checkbox-tree)

The package uses a similar structure, the difference is that each level has additional properties, and it's children (if any) are in a list. This is the output that I am trying to achieve.

```
[
  {
    "label": "Analyzer1",
    "value": "analyzer1",
    "children": [
      {
        "label": "Mode1",
        "value": "analyzer1/mode1",
        "children": [
          {
            "label": "SubMode1",
            "value": "analyzer1/mode1/submode1",
            "children": [
              {
                "label": "Filename2",
                "value": "analyzer1/mode1/submode1/filename2",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "label": "Signal1",
                    "value": "analyzer1/mode1/submode1/filename2/signal1"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "label": "Mode2",
        "value": "analyzer1/mode2",
        "children": [
          {
            "label": "SubMode2",
            "value": "analyzer1/mode2/submode2",
            "children": [
              {
                "label": "Filename1",
                "value": "analyzer1/mode2/submode2/filename1",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "label": "Signal2",
                    "value": "analyzer1/mode2/submode2/filename1/signal2"
                  },
                  {
                    "label": "Signal3",
                    "value": "analyzer1/mode2/submode2/filename1/signal3"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "label": "Mode3",
        "value": "analyzer1/mode3",
        "children": [
          {
            "label": "SubMode1",
            "value": "analyzer1/mode3/submode1",
            "children": [ 
              {
                "label": "Filename1",
                "value": "analyzer1/mode3/submode1/filename1",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "label": "Signal2",
                    "value": "analyzer1/mode3/submode1/filename1/signal2"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "label": "SubMode3",
            "value": "analyzer1/mode3/submode3",
            "children": [ 
              {
                "label": "Filename1",
                "value": "analyzer1/mode3/submode3/filename1",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "label": "Signal3",
                    "value": "analyzer1/mode3/submode3/filename1/signal3"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Analyzer2",
    "value": "analyzer2",
    "children": [
      {
        "label": "Mode1",
        "value": "analyzer2/mode1",
        "children": [
          {
            "label": "SubMode4",
            "value": "analyzer2/mode1/submode4",
            "children": [
              {
                "label": "Filename1",
                "value": "analyzer2/mode1/submode4/filename1",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "label": "Signal2",
                    "value": "analyzer2/mode1/submode4/filename1/signal2"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I've tried the following, but it is incomplete, I can't find a way to add the children to the parent node.

```
def adjust(d, res, parent, children, path):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if(not isinstance(v, list)):
                path = path + k.lower() + '/'
                parent['value'] = k.lower()
                parent['label'] = k
                adjust(v, res, parent['children'][0], path)
            else:
                parent['children'] = []
            res.append(parent)
adjust(d, [], {}, [], '')
```

Any suggestions or pointers would be appreciated, I'm not very skilled at doing recursion.

Comment: The example input and the desired output seem unrelated. It is not clear therefore what maps to what.

Comment: Okay, I'll rewrite the output, thank you

Comment: done @trincot, hopefully it's clear now, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive function should not have that many arguments. Let it build its subtree autonomously, only needing the path as extra information from the caller. And make it *functional*, so that it *returns* the result for the subtree it deals with. That way the caller can inject the result in its own `children` attributes.

Here is how that could work:

```
def maketree(d, path=""):
    if isinstance(d, list):
        return [{ 
            "label": k,
            "value": path + k.lower()
        } for k in d]
    else:
        return [{
            "label": k,
            "value": path + k.lower(),
            "children": maketree(v, path + k.lower() + "/")
        } for k, v in d.items()]
```

Call it as:

```
tree = maketree(d)
```